# Python - Why is the function not working when reading from file?

Tags: python, function, file, exception

This is the code i have used

```
file
```

Comment: Please share the output of an execution. `lines` does contains multiple lines as the name suggest, only ONE, is that normal ?

Comment: I'm sure your code *does* run, its just that its not doing what you expect.

Comment: My code does run but it does not run this section of the code

Comment: I'm sure your code *does* run this section of the code, its just that its not doing what you expect.

Comment: Why is not doing what I expect?

Comment: Because it’s a computer program and your expectations are not aligned with how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to read all the lines from the file and look at the last one. Like this:

```py
try:
    lines = myfile.readlines()
    GetTopic = lines[-1].strip()
    ...
```

Your code read one line into `lines` and `lines[-1]` was a single character and `GetTopic = print(lines[-1])` meant that `GetTopic` was `None` and so not equal to any of your literal strings.

Comment: I tried this and it still does not work

Comment: Ok, perhaps the `.readlines()` method is also including line endings like: `\n`. You could try using `.strip()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: You’ll have to give more details than that. What happens if you add print(GetTopic)?

Comment: In the external file, the last line is 'Industries', when I print GetTopic, it prints 's' which I assume is the last letter of Industries

Comment: UPDATE - I managed the GetTopic to print the last line by removing the -1, the print(GetTopic) prints the topic on the last line but the function still doesn't run.

Comment: So, what is the first line of the file? Perhaps you could include a few sample lines from one of your files.

Comment: first line = x7545354n36436n3nnmm34545 - #hashed password this is not included in the file.

Comment: second line = Language

Comment: So what if you add: `print(repr(GetTopic))`?

Comment: It prints 'Language\n'

Comment: So that's why I think that my code: `lines = myfile.readlines()` which reads the whole file and: `GetTopic = lines[-1].strip()` which gets the last line, but without the `\n` should mean that then `if GetTopic == "Industries":` should be a match.

Comment: It is working now, thank you so much.

Comment: So, how did you fix it in the end?

Comment: I changed the functions to see if the error was from the functions, but it wasn't. I then added the readlines() instead of readline() and removing rstrip() and added strip().

Comment: Pretty much what you originally suggested but it just was not working.

Comment: I am getting another error. Pretty much my code only allows me to write one topic into the file and doesn't let me right other topics. It prints the except message whenever there is already a topic in the file but the code works when there is no topic in the file.  The code is as follows: def FileWrite(x): \n myfile.write(x) \n  if .... == ....: \n try: \n FileWrite(x="Language") \n except: \n print("Could not write to file")

Comment: It sounds like its time for a new question.

Comment: I have created the question.

Answer (score 0):

- `readline()` returns a string - the first line of the document.
- `readlines()` returns an array, which is probably what you're expecting.

  - I prefer to use `lines = [x.strip() for x in myfile.readlines()]`
- The result of assigning a `print()` is always `None`. Python isn't the command line.

Comment: I am looking for a string in the external file, not an array

Comment: It's an array of strings...